# Database change dont work

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Im trying to update a whole lot of posts on my website through the database/phpmyadmin.

**My Mission:
I'd like to unpublish a bunch of posts which have a certain catergory (term).
Posts and terms have their own column in the database.
**

I've entered this SQL query:

```
Update posts
SET posts.post_status = 'draft'
WHERE terms.term_id = 4 and posts.post_type ='post'
```

This should work,  but I get this message:
1054 -  unknown column in where clause (terms.term_id ).

This is very strange, because phpmyadmin suggests this column itself while entering the query. Any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: you didn't specify what `terms` is

Comment: Is there a `term_id` on the `posts` table?

Comment: your query makes absolutely no sense... you're updating a posts-table, based on a terms-statement which isn't in any way related to the posts table. I'd suggest you reading some basic tutorials on mysql.

Comment: No there isn't @WEI_DBA. 

a POST can have 0 or more TERMs (from the term column).

Comment: Do I have to join them? @ad_on_is  Could you post  a suggestion besides the tutorial please?

Comment: Whether you have to join them or not, depends strongly on your desired result. Google is always your friend, my friend: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+tutorial+basic

Comment: Thanks, there appears to be no direct relation (see picture). Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the inbetween tables in the query:

```
Update posts
INNER JOIN terms, term_relationships, term_taxonomy
SET posts.post_status = 'draft'
WHERE terms.term_id = 4 and posts.post_type ='post'
```